# Quantum Mechanics - Finding momentum probability density

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, fourier-transform

everyone. I got a bit stuck on 2(iii), this is supposed to be a easy question, but i don't know how you get the square term? I thought you just do the Fourier transform, but then I got some exponential out of it and I don't know what to do? Can anyone suggest or shed some light on the problem? THANKS
If you just plug in infinity into the integral, how can you avoid the problem of getting zero?

[image]

[image]

You may use the integral provided.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about what you've tried and why you think it is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that  $\left|\psi\left(x\right)\right\rangle =\int\left|\varphi_{p}\left(x\right)\right\rangle \left\langle \varphi_{p}\left(x\right)|\psi\left(x\right)\right\rangle dp$
  (for continuous p)

Where $\left\langle \varphi_{p}\left(x\right)|\psi\left(x\right)\right\rangle=\text{Φ}\left(p\right)$, which is the amplitude of momentum measurement $p$

Then $\text{Φ}\left(p\right)=\left\langle \varphi_{p}\left(x\right)|\psi\left(x\right)\right\rangle =\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{\varphi_{p}}\left(x\right)\psi\left(x\right)dx$

=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a\bar{h}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-\left|x\right|}{a}+ix\left(k-\frac{P}{\bar{h}}\right)}dx$

By solving the integral, you get

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a\bar{h}}}\left(-\frac{1}{\frac{-1}{a}+i\left(k-\frac{P}{\bar{h}}\right)}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+i\left(k-\frac{P}{\bar{h}}\right)}\right)$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a\bar{h}}}\left(\frac{2a}{1+a^{2}\left(k-\frac{P}{\bar{h}}\right)^{2}}\right)$

which can then be simplified to obtain the answer provided

Comment: how do you get 1 for the numerator?, if you sub infinite to x ...

Comment: I split the integral into two parts, modified the negative part, and use the integral provided to get the two fraction.